# SELECT Product rows with expired date

Tags: sql, oracle, select

i have a table as follows:

> PRODUCT(P_CODE, DESCRIPTION, PRODUCTION_DATE)

the expired product are  those have been produced more than 1 year. How do I list all the products that have already expired & together with their expiration date ?

Comment: Is P_CODE unique or can there be multiple rows with the same P_CODE value but different PRODUCTION_DATE values?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
create table PRODUCT(P_CODE number, DESCRIPTION varchar2(200), PRODUCTION_DATE date);

insert into product values(1,'XXX',to_date('12-03-2013','dd-mm-yyyy'));

insert into product values(2,'YYY',to_date('13-03-2012','dd-mm-yyyy'));

insert into product values(3,'ZZZ',to_date('12-08-2012','dd-mm-yyyy'));

insert into product values(4,'AAA',to_date('16-08-2013','dd-mm-yyyy'));   

select p_code
      ,description
      ,production_date
      ,add_months(production_date,12) expire_date  
 from product
where production_date<add_months(sysdate,-12)
```

[image: output]

Answer (score 4):

```
SELECT  P_CODE,PRODUCTION_DATE
FROM    PRODUCT
WHERE   PRODUCTION_DATE >= NOW() - INTERVAL 12 MONTH
```

Comment: Thanks for pointing out, for oracle, the WHERE statement should be: PRODUCTION_DATE <= ADD_MONTHS(TRUNC(SYSDATE), -12)

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how it's done in oracle, but in MS SQL it is:

```
SELECT P_CODE, DESCRIPTION, PRODUCTION_DATE
FROM PRODUCT
WHERE PRODUCTION_DATE < DATEADD(yy, -1, GETUTCDATE())
```

Answer (score 0):

`SELECT * 
FROM PRODUCT 
WHERE DATEDIFF(YEAR,CURDATE(),DATE_ADD(PRODUCTION_DATE, INTERVAL 1 YEAR)) > 1`

That's a wag at it but [THIS LINK](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/sql/sql-date-functions.htm) should get you where you want to go